# Accessing Nested Attributes When Doing Error Checking In Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 application where I have one model related to several models.  I will give information about one of them related models to explain the scenario.  I have new and edit views that I use in my maintenance screen.  I am still pretty new to working with nested attributes.  My maintenance screen allows maintenance of a row with associated attributes.  I manually grab the selected rows and write them out associated with my parent row.  I display them in a list on top of the collection_select drop down list box.  However with doing some recent checking after some problems with 500 errors I noticed that I had some software problems I need to correct.

I have my error checking code in the update method where I render edit after finding the error.  When it attempts to display the edit view I get a 500 error where it is trying to find the array of one of my nested attributes.  Here is an error I recently got.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `topic_id' for {"topic_id"=>[""]}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess):
    56:     <p style="padding-left: 150px; color: #f8ee5f;"><%= display_topics @media_library %></p>
    57: <% end %>
    58: <%= fields_for :media_topics do |media_topic| %>
    59:   <%= media_topic.label :topic, "Topics" %><%= media_topic.collection_select(:topic_id, Topic.order("name_en"), :id, :name_en, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
    60: <% end %><br>
    61: 
    62: <% if @media_library.media_targets.count > 0 %>
  app/views/media_libraries/_media_library_fields.html.erb:59:in `block in _app_views_media_libraries__media_library_fields_html_erb___4316101037373251257_70115028003400'
  app/views/media_libraries/_media_library_fields.html.erb:58:in `_app_views_media_libraries__media_library_fields_html_erb___4316101037373251257_70115028003400'
  app/views/media_libraries/edit.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_media_libraries_edit_html_erb__2448603971022600459_70115028733680'
  app/views/media_libraries/edit.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_media_libraries_edit_html_erb__2448603971022600459_70115028733680'
  app/controllers/media_libraries_controller.rb:115:in `update'
```

Here is how I have my MediaLibrary model defined related to the MediaTopic model.  I'm only including the portions of the models that relate to my question.

```
class MediaLibrary < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :media_topics_attributes
  has_many :media_topics, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :media_topics

class MediaTopic < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :media_library
```

Here is the my edit method:

```
def edit
  @media_library = MediaLibrary.find(params[:id])
  @edit_page     = true
end
```

This statement is where I grab the array of selected media_topics from the collection_select for the Topic model (where media_topics gets its topic_id value related to the MediaLibrary model)

```
@media_topics  = params[:media_topics]
```

Here is a sample of the error checking in the update method.

```
case
when params[:link].blank?         && params[:link_video].blank? && params[:link_pdf].blank? && params[:resource].blank? && params[:resource2].blank? && params[:resource3].blank?
  flash.now[:error] = "You must enter at least one link before creating a Media Library Item."
  render 'edit'
else
  some update logic here
end
```

Here is the code from my edit view.  The display_topics helper displays the list of related topic rows above the drop down list of topics.

```
<% if @media_library.media_topics.count > 0 %>
  <p style="padding-left: 150px; color: #f8ee5f;"><%= display_topics @media_library %></p>
<% end %>
<%= fields_for :media_topics do |media_topic| %>
  <%= media_topic.label :topic, "Topics" %><%= media_topic.collection_select(:topic_id, Topic.order("name_en"), :id, :name_en, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
<% end %><br>
```

Here is the display_topics helper:

```
  def display_topics(media_library)

    media_library_topics = MediaTopic.where("media_library_id = ?", media_library.id).all
    topic_list = nil;
    if media_library_topics
      i = 1
      media_library_topics.each do |mltopic|
        topic_row = Topic.find(mltopic.topic_id)
        case I18n.locale.to_s
        when "fr"
          topic_name = topic_row.name_fr
        when "pt"
          topic_name = topic_row.name_pt
        when "es"
          topic_name = topic_row.name_es
        else
          topic_name = topic_row.name_en
        end
        if i == 1
          if media_library_topics.size == 1 
            topic_list = "#{t :media_label_topic}: "+topic_name
          else
            topic_list = "#{t :media_label_topics}: "+topic_name
          end
        else  
          topic_list = topic_list+" | "+topic_name
        end
        i += 1
      end
      "#{topic_list}"
    end

  end
```

I do not know of another way to work with the nested_attributes than to manually add them or delete/re-add them.

What I do not know is that when I render 'edit' a second time what happens to the nested attributes from the form?  From what I am seeing in this error it seems like this disappear, hence the undefined method :topic_id.

I have done a lot of searching off and on since I developed this function but I have not seen this error mentioned.  All of the examples I remember do not show situations with nested attributes where a person is rendering the edit view back to back, first to initially display the records then to show errors.

How do I get my nested attributes back to the view a second time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't read through your whole question, but I usually check for empty params using `!params[:name]` - if it can help.

Comment: The problem is probably related to how I am processing the rows from media_topics.  I am manually adding/deleting them using the Topic model that a person selects from.  An empty hash/array is valid in this instance.  I need to figure out how to get it to display properly.  Either that or there may be another way for me to do this process.  I will submit another question related to that issue which may solve this problem where I will not have an empty hash when trying to display my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing more research and noticed that when using **fields_for** in a form it is designated as **f.fields_for**, not fields_for as I have them in my application.  I changed the view to use **f.fields_for** and noticed that the selected options are appearing in my drop down list for the Topic model.  Hopefully this will take care of the problem I was having in my other question.  At least I am no longer getting the 500 error.  I will probably rewrite the code I have for updating the MediaTopic rows in my controller since now it is using the media_topic_attributes in my view.